# Compile against a outdated explicit instantiation of a template

Tags: c++, linker, c++17

I use a library (Orocos) which defines its own `std::basic_string` with a custom allocator. In addition, it explicitely instantiate it:

```
namespace RTT
{
    typedef std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, RTT::os::rt_allocator<char> > rt_string;
}

namespace std
{
    extern template class basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, RTT::os::rt_allocator<char> >;
}
```

This worked well until I switched to C++17. In C++ 17, `std::basic_string` has new functions, namely a non const version of `data()`. Now, when I compile, I get undefined references to `RTT::rt_string::data()`, because Orocos is unaware of C++17.

What is the most "correct" thing to do?

- Patch the library to compile at least the template instantiations in C++17.
- Patch the library to not explicitly instantiate this class.
- Do not use those methods. I can cope with that, but I would have to do something like `const_cast<RTT::rt_string const&>(myString).data()` everytime I use the method on a non-const object. Also, if I forgot, I will have strange linker error again.
- Add those symbols in my library, somehow.
- `data()` is an implicit inline function, if I compile in release the problem should be gone. Not really a solution.

Comment: Even if the explicit instantiation was not there you should first check if the standard library abi used to compile Orocos can be compatible with the one you are using. I suspect the answer will be no. If you succeed to link, execution may result in bad surprises.

Comment: We used the same compiler (GCC9) to compile both library, so there should be no ABI incompatibility or _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI problems.

Comment: Have you tried to compile Orocos with `-std=c++17`?

Comment: @Oliv I can, but I prefer not to compile my dependencies myself when I can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to add an explicit instantiation **definition** for the missing member function to your own code (in exactly one source file):

```
template char* std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, RTT::os::rt_allocator<char> >::data() noexcept;
```

This is not strictly conforming in that member function signatures in the standard library are not guaranteed, but using two language versions together is already beyond the formal scope of the standard (and it would be an ODR violation to use two different versions of any program-defined class (template) in this fashion).